# Преобразовать строки в ссылки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Есть текстовый файл:

```
AAA-1
BBB-2
CCC-3
```

Как преобразовать средствами JS или JQUERY текстовые строки в ссылки и сделать вывод в таблицу?

Через notepad++ делаю так:

1. Найти ^ заменить на `<a href="URL">`
2. Найти $ заменить на `</a>`

А идея загрузить файл через HTML5 - и сделать вывод ссылок в  таблицу.

Comment: Ссылки должны получиться примерно такие: `<a href="AAA-1">AAA-1</a>`

Comment: Файл  читаю кодом https://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/KjEHg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let str = "AAA-1 \n BBB-2 \n CCC-3 \n DDDDDDD-4"; // Переносы строки, \n
           
let links = document.getElementById('links');

str = str.replace(/\s+($)/gm,"$1").replace(/(^)\s+/gm,"$1") // Удаляем пробелы вначале и в конце
         .replace(/^(.+)$/gm, `<tr><td><a href="$1">$1</a></td></tr>`);

links.innerHTML = str;
console.log( str );
```

```css
#links { border-collapse: collapse; }
#links td {
  background-color: #923;
  border: 1px solid #500;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
#links td a { color: white; }
```

```html
<table id="links"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

вариант с jquery без регулярок (непонятно зачем нужным тут вообще)

```js
var txt = "AAA-1\nBBB-2\nCCC-3";

txt.split("\n").forEach( function(s){
   $("<a>").text(s).attr('href', s).appendTo("body");
});

// или
//  $("body").append( 
//        txt.split("\n").map(s => `<a href="${s}">${s}</a>`) 
//  );
```

```css
a { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: (например) - будет два переноса строки, split создаст дополнительный пустой элемент...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME если вдруг будет, то `trim()` решит эту проблему

Comment: Все коды работают, теперь осталась задача- как в данную строку поместить содержимое файла без явных  \n (((

Comment: @Максим в смысле?